# Convergence of a sequence defined by $ c_{n+1}=\frac{r_{n+1}\sqrt{c_n}}{3}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Define a sequence $(r_n)$ by $r_0=1$ and $r_{n+1}=(2/3)r_n+1$ for $n\geq 0$. Let the sequence $(c_n)$ be defined by $c_0=1/4$, and
>   $$
> c_{n+1}=\frac{r_{n+1}\sqrt{c_n}}{3}
> $$
>   for $n\geq 0$. Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n$ exists.

---

It is not difficult to prove that the sequence $(r_n)$ converges to $3$ since it is bounded above and non-decreasing. I don't have a more useful estimate for $(c_n)$ than $c_{n+1}\leq \sqrt{c_n}$. How shall I go on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enlightened by answers and comments, I have a proof. 
One can see that $r_{n+1}-3=\frac{2}{3}(r_n-3),$ which implies by induction that 
$$
r_{n}-3=(r_0-3)q^n,\quad q=2/3,
$$
and thus 
$$
c_{n+1}=\left(1-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n+2}\right)\cdot\sqrt{c_n}=:b_n\sqrt{c_n}. 
$$

On the other hand, $c_1\geq c_0$ by direct calculation. Suppose $c_{n+1}\geq c_n$. Then 
$$
c_{n+2}=b_{n+1}\sqrt{c_{n+1}}\geq b_n\sqrt{c_{n+1}}\geq b_n\sqrt{c_n}=c_{n+1}.
$$
It follows that $(c_n)$ is a non-decreasing sequence.

All we need to do now is showing that $(c_n)$ is bounded above. We use induction again. Obviously $c_0\leq 1$. Suppose $c_n\leq 1$. Then 
$$
c_{n+1}\leq\sqrt{c_n}\leq 1. 
$$
We are done.

Comment: Reflection. The inequality $c_{n+1}\leq\sqrt{c_n}$ in OP is useful in the sense that it actually gives a half of the proof: it shows that the sequence $(c_n)$ is bounded. In order to show that $c_n$ is monotone so that one can use the convergence theorem, one needs to exploit properties of $(r_n)$, the expression of which can be *explicitly* calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the recursion of $\,r_n\,$ in the recursion of $\,c_n\,$ we get

$\displaystyle b_n:=\frac{c_{n+1}}{\sqrt{c_n}}= \frac{2}{3} b_{n-1}+\frac{1}{3}=…=1+(\frac{2}{3})^n(b_0-1)$

with $\enspace\displaystyle b_0= \frac{c_1}{\sqrt{c_0}} =\frac{r_1}{3} =\frac{1}{3} (\frac{2}{3}r_0 +1)= \frac{5}{9} $ .

The recursion for $\,c_n\,$ is now $\enspace\displaystyle c_n=b_{n-1} \sqrt{c_{n-1}}=(1-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n+1})\sqrt{c_{n-1}} $ .

It's $\enspace\displaystyle \ln c_n=-\frac{\ln 2}{2^{n-1}}+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^k}\ln\left(1-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n+1-k}\right)$

and with $\enspace\displaystyle \ln\frac{5}{9}\leq \ln\left(1-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n+1-k}\right)<0$

we get $\enspace\displaystyle -\frac{\ln 2}{2^{n-1}}+2(\ln\frac{5}{9})(1-\frac{1}{2^n})\leq\ln c_n<-\frac{\ln 2}{2^{n-1}}$

and therefore $\enspace\displaystyle \frac{25}{81}\leq c_\infty \leq 1$ .

$\enspace\displaystyle c_0=\frac{1}{4}<\frac{25}{81}\enspace$ implies that the sequence of $\,(c_n)\,$ is increasing

and therefore exists a well defined limit $\,c_\infty\,$ .

Now we get directly $\,c_\infty=1\,$ from the recursion for $\,c_n\,$ above.

*Note:*

The easiest way to show directly that the sequence $(c_n)$ is increasing is induction, which is mentioned in *Jack*'s answer.

Comment: $c_n$ is *increassing* and $\sqrt{c_{n-1}} > c_{n-1}$ because $c_{n-1} < 1$.

Comment: @user90369 : I think that you can finish in the following way: Put $u_j=\log(1-(\frac{2}{3})^j)$ , we have to study $$T_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^k}u_{n-k}$$
We verify that 

$$T_n=\frac{2^{n+1}-2}{2^n}\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n 2^j u_j}{\sum_{j=1}^n 2^j}$$

Now as $u_j\to 0$, we can apply Cesaro's Theorem: we get that $T_n\to0$, and hence that $\log c_n\to 0$, and this show that $c_n\to 1$. (Note that your -log(2) at the beginning of the formula seems to be not correct. I have found $\log(c_0)/2^n)$)

Comment: @Ihf : I have understood now, thanks!

Comment: @Kelenner : Thanks a lot for your explanation! --- I corrected my mistake. $T_n$ is interesting (I still will check it) but with $c_0<\frac{25}{81}$ (after removing the mistake) we know, that $c_\infty$ exists and we can use the recursion for $c_n$ to get $c_\infty=1$ directly.